# Stored Procedure: Passing a parameter when using dynamic SQL for pivoting data

Tags: sql-server, string, parameter-passing, dynamic-sql

As the title suggests, I'm trying use dynamic SQL to get column names for a pivoted table - however, I also want to be able to pass a parameter to a variable called @assessments, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Below is the code I'm using, would appreciate if anyone could take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong. Thank you

```
    create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTestExamResults]

    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @ColumnName as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @assessment as NVARCHAR(50)

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Get distinct values from pivot source

    SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(subjectname)

    From (SELECT DISTINCT SubjectName From qryPupilNCTest) as p order by p.Subjectname

    SET @SQL = 
    'select pupil,PupilName, year' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM qrypupilnctest
    Where assessment in (' + @assessment + ')
    PIVOT (MAX(grade) for subjectname in (' +@ColumnName + ')) piv'


    EXEC (@SQL)

    END
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting errors?  Incorrect Results?

Comment: You want the `@assessment` as the parameter instead of the local variable? Your question is not clear!

Comment: As coded this will never return anything because your assessment variable has not been assigned a value, therefore your sql variable is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `@assessment` is the local variable with out any initialization and handled in the operation. So it always have empty value only and you won't get any result from the stored procedure.

As per your post title, you can alter the stored procedure and pass the `@assessment` as parameter, so the `WHERE assessment IN (` will have some valid data and you will receive some valid result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTestExamResults]
(
  @assessment   NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    -- DECLARE @assessment as NVARCHAR(50)  -- Remove the @assessment from the local variable 

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Get distinct values from pivot source
    SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(subjectname)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SubjectName FROM qryPupilNCTest) AS p 
    ORDER BY p.Subjectname

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT pupil, PupilName, year' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM qrypupilnctest
    WHERE assessment IN (' + @assessment + ')
    PIVOT (MAX(grade) FOR subjectname IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) piv'

    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

So the execution call will be:

```
EXEC [dbo].[spTestExamResults] 'paramvalue1, paramvalue2'
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question - I was executing the sproc and getting no results returned, as Sean Lange pointed out would happen. However, Arulkumar's response has made me realise that it was a case of putting it in the wrong place - once I put it where it should be, it worked perfectly. I'm a relative newbie to SQL, so I was swimming quite some way out of my depth. Thanks very much for your help everyone, special thanks to Arulkumar!